# Как наложить Polygon Colider на спрайт в Unty?

Tags: unity3d, 2d, спрайт

Сейчас создаю коллайдер, как **AddComponent< PolygonCollider2D >()**. Есть ли более точный стандартный метод наложение **Polygon Collider** на спрайт?

**P.S.** Если делать свой, то какой способ будет наиболее быстрым?

[image: Polygon Collider]